# CSS/JS problem: found a solution to have page/menu that overlap with their respective scrollbars

Tags: css, angular, typescript

I have a problem with a scrollbar. The problem is a fullscreen menu that comes on a page and resets the page scollbar due to a `display: none`.

The following images will explain better than me.

[image: image that will explain the problem better than me]

The TypeScript code:

```js
// PROBLEM: The method that toogle the menu by adding a css class with 'display: none'.
toggleMenu() { 
  const main = document.getElementById('main'); 
  if (main !== null) { 
    if (this.menuOpen) { 
      this.menuOpen = false; 
      main.classList.remove('hidden'); 
    } else { 
      this.menuOpen = true; 
      setTimeout(() => this.menuOpen ? main.classList.add('hidden') : null, 250); 
    } 
  } 
}
```

The HTML code:

```html
<label class="main-menu">
  <input type='checkbox' #checkbox (click)="toggleMenu()">
  <span class='menu'><span class='hamburger'></span></span>
  <div class="theme-menu">
    <app-theme-switcher></app-theme-switcher>
  </div>
  <ul class="pb-4 pt-2">
    <li><a routerLink="/home" (click)="toggleMenu()">Accueil</a></li>
  </ul>
</label>

<main id="main">
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</main>

<app-footer></app-footer>
```

And the CSS code:

```scss
.hidden {
  display: none !important;
  opacity: 0;
}
.main-menu {
  *, *:before, *:after {
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }
  .menu {
    position: fixed;
    right: -100px;
    top: -100px;
    z-index: 100;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background: $background-color;
    border-radius: 50% 50% 50% 50%;
    -webkit-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
    transition: .5s ease-in-out;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 $animation-color, 0 0 0 0 $animation-color;
    cursor: pointer;
    &:hover .hamburger, &:hover .hamburger:before, &:hover .hamburger:after {
      background: $text-color-active !important;
    }
  }
  .hamburger {
    position: absolute;
    top: 135px;
    left: 50px;
    width: 30px;
    height: 2px;
    background: $hamburger-color;
    display: block;
    -webkit-transform-origin: center;
    transform-origin: center;
    -webkit-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
    transition: .5s ease-in-out;
    &:before, &:after {
      -webkit-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
      transition: .5s ease-in-out;
      content: "";
      position: absolute;
      display: block;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      background: $hamburger-color;
    }
    
    &:before {
      top: -10px;
    }
    &:after {
      bottom: -10px;
    }
  }
  //animation for the full screen menu
  input:checked + .menu {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 125vw $background-color, 0 0 0 100vh $background-color; //120 to avoid broken animations
    border-radius: 0;
  }
  //animation for the burger
  input:checked {
      &+ .menu .hamburger {
      -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
      transform: rotate(45deg);
        &:after, &:before {
          -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
          transform: rotate(90deg);
        }
        &:after {
          bottom: 0;
        }
        &:before {
          top: 0;
        }
    }
  }
  input {
    display: none;
    &:checked + .menu + .theme-menu + ul { //show the ul list
      opacity: 1;
      visibility: visible;
      -webkit-transition: visibility 0s, opacity .5s .25s ease-in-out;
      transition: visibility 0s, opacity .5s .25s ease-in-out;
    }
    &:checked + .menu + .theme-menu {
      opacity: 1;
      visibility: visible;
      -webkit-transition: visibility 0s, opacity .5s .25s ease-in-out;
      transition: visibility 0s, opacity .5s .25s ease-in-out;
    }
  }
  .theme-menu {
    z-index: 200;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 58px;
    right: 58px;
    zoom: 75%;
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
  }
  ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    z-index: 200;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, 0);
    transform: translate(-50%, 0);
    -webkit-transition: visibility 0s .25s, opacity .25s ease-in-out;
    transition: visibility 0s .25s, opacity .25s ease-in-out;
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    padding: 0;
    li {
      a:hover {
        color: $text-color-active;
        transition: color .5s ease-in-out;
      }
      .active {
        color: $text-color-active;
      }
    }
  }
  a {
    font-size: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 0.5em;
    padding-top: 0.5em;
    display: block;
    color: $text-color;
    text-decoration: none;
  }
}
```

Do you have a solution?

Thank you,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to this problem:

I updated the `.hidden` to this:

```css
.hidden::-webkit-scrollbar { 
  display: none;  /* Safari and Chrome */
}
```

and apply this style to the `body` instead of the `#main` element.